# How to use sidekiq with devise to send emails without devise-async

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, sidekiq

I am currently developing a rails 4 application. I use devise for authentication. I want to use Sidekiq to send emails. I found this tuto https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Devise but I cannot figure out where I should put the name of the queue. Can anyone help me with a gist. Thank you

Comment: That page already shows how to configure the queue name, look closer https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Devise#use-devise-async

Comment: Thank you Mike, I don't want add devise-async. I followed the "Do it your self" section and I get it running. As I configured many queues I do not know which one is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the code snippet shown on that wiki page, you can do this:

```
Devise::Mailer.delay(queue: 'my_queue').send(...)
```

Answer (score 9):

Once you have Sidekiq added to your rails app (see [link to getting started](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Getting-Started)) In order to use devise with Sidekiq (without devise-async) you can use rails built in ActiveJob. Put this override function in the model that devise is implemented in:

```
 def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
  devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
 end
```

configure Sideiq with ActiveJob

```
# config/application.rb

class Application < Rails::Application
  # ...
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
end
```

And set up your mailers queue for Sidekiq

```
# config/sidekiq.yml

---
:concurrency: 1
:queues:
  - default
  - mailers
```

Also redis should be installed to hold job data for sidekiq, its all given in more detail [here](https://gist.github.com/maxivak/690e6c353f65a86a4af9)